# Circle in place of black node in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, circles

Question:

In my graph i want to draw small circles in place of black dots for every points a, b, c, d, e, f and g. further i want to label all these points inside circle.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (0,4)-- (0,0);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (0,0)-- (4,0);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (4,4)-- (4,0);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (4,4)-- (0,4);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (4,4)-- (7,2);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (7,2)-- (4,0);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (0,4)-- (-3,2);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (-3,2)-- (0,0);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (0,4)-- (2,2);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (2,2)-- (4,4);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (2,2)-- (4,0);
    \draw [line width=0.5pt] (2,2)-- (0,0);
    \draw [fill=black] (0,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (0,-0.35) node {$c$};
    \draw [fill=black] (0,4) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (-0.02,4.35) node {$b$};
    \draw [fill=black] (4,4) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (3.98,4.35) node {$e$};
    \draw [fill=black] (4,0) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (4.0,-0.35) node {$f$};
    \draw [fill=black] (7,2) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (7.32,2.0) node {$g$};
    \draw [fill=black] (-3,2) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (-3.32,2.0) node {$a$};
    \draw [fill=black] (2,2) circle (1.5pt);
    \draw[color=black] (2.0,2.54) node {$d$};
    \draw[color=black] (-0.24,2.0) node {$4$};
    \draw[color=black] (2,-0.26) node {$2$};
    \draw[color=black] (4.26,2.0) node {$3$};
    \draw[color=black] (2.0,4.250) node {$7$};
    \draw[color=black] (5.56,3.35) node {$10$};
    \draw[color=black] (5.56,0.65) node {$12$};
    \draw[color=black] (-1.46,3.40) node {$1$};
    \draw[color=black] (-1.46,0.65) node {$5$};
    \draw[color=black] (0.78,2.9) node {$8$};
    \draw[color=black] (3.3,2.9) node {$11$};
    \draw[color=black] (3.3,1.0) node {$9$};
    \draw[color=black] (0.78,1.10) node {$6$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not new comer here: you have asked 80 questions, most of them got answers. However, still you keep asking simple questions. Moreover, you code is very very far from clean, far from TikZ style. Instead of answering your question, I recommend reading TikZ manual again and again.

Comment: @Blackmind I will follow your advise.  I will not ask single question until I properly read Tikz manual. Thanks

Comment: this is Mild, not mind. My mind is not black, lol

Comment: Sorry for typing mistake. It was not intentionally. Once again extremely sorry.

Comment: Hoping that you will forgive me for this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be simplified quite a bit. One way to do that is to draw the vertices first. This is what the first path command does. Then one may realize that one possible path that draws all the connections without drawing any twice is the cycle

```
(c) -- (f) -- (e) -- (g) -- (f) -- (d) -- (b) -- (a) -- (c) -- (b) -- (e) -- (d) -- (c)
```

One can insert edge labels by adding `node` right after `--`. This is what the `\draw` command does. There are little helpers like the `math` style (which is adapted from the `matrix of math nodes` style) which allows us to avoid typing `$` like crazy.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[circ/.style={circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,minimum
  size=3.4ex},math/.style={execute at begin node=$,execute at end node=$}]
    \path[nodes={circ,math}] (0,0) node(c){c}  
     (4,0) node(f){f} 
     (4,4) node(e){e} 
     (7,2) node(g){g}
     (0,4) node(b){b} 
     (-3,2) node(a){a} 
     (2,2) node(d){d};
    \draw[line width=0.5pt,nodes={auto,math}]     
     (c) -- node{2} (f) -- node{3} (e) -- node{10} (g) -- node{12} (f) 
      -- node{9} (d) -- node{8} (b) -- node{1} (a) -- node{5} (c) 
      -- node{4} (b) -- node{7} (e)  -- node{11} (d)  -- node{6} (c);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really new things for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way with plain TikZ. It is not as concise as the answer of Schrodinger's cat, but easier to follow.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[n/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=8mm,inner sep=0}]
\path 
(0,0)   node[n] (d) {$d$}  
(2,2)   node[n] (e) {$e$} 
(2,-2)  node[n] (f) {$f$} 
(-2,2)  node[n] (b) {$b$}
(-2,-2) node[n] (c) {$c$} 
(-5,0)  node[n] (a) {$a$} 
(5,0)   node[n] (g) {$g$};
\draw (a)--(b) node[pos=.5,below right]{$1$};
\draw (b)--(c) node[pos=.5,left]{$4$};
\draw (c)--(d) node[pos=.5,below right]{$6$};
\draw (d)--(e) node[pos=.5,above left]{$11$};
\draw (e)--(f) node[pos=.5,left]{$3$};
\draw (f)--(g) node[pos=.5,below right]{$12$};
\draw (g)--(e) node[pos=.5,above right]{$10$};
\draw (e)--(b) node[pos=.5,above]{$7$};
\draw (a)--(c) node[pos=.5,above right]{$5$};
\draw (c)--(f) node[pos=.5,above]{$2$};
\draw (b)--(d) node[pos=.5,above right]{$8$};
\draw (d)--(f) node[pos=.5,below left]{$9$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Mild Thanks a lot sir. I express my sincere respect.